# How to check if symfony messenger is working

Tags: worker, php-8, symfony-messenger, symfony5.4

I have a pod running in kubernetes / aws cloud. Due to limited configuration options in a custom deployment process (not my fault!!) I cannot start the symfony messenger as you usually would start it. What I have to do after a deployment is log into the shell and manually do
`bin/console messenger:consume my_kafka_messages`

Of course as soon as the pod for any reason is automatically restarted my worker isn't running. So until we can change the company deployment process I have to make sure to at least get notice if the worker isn't running.

**Is there any option to e.g. run an symfony command which checks if the worker is running?** If that was possible I could let the system start the worker or at least send me a notification.

How about
`bin/console debug:messenger`
?

If I do that and get e.g. this output is this  sign that the worker is running? Or is it just the configuration of a worker, which could run, if it were started and may or may not run currently?

```bash
$ bin/console deb:mess

Messenger
=========

events
------

 The following messages can be dispatched:

 --------------------------------------------------
  @codeCoverageIgnore
  App\Domain\KafkaEvents\ProductPictureCollection
      handled by App\Handler\ProductPictureHandler

 --------------------------------------------------
```

Of course I can do a crude approach and check the db, which logs the processed datasets. But t is always possible that for e.g. 5 days there are no data to process. In that case I would get false alarms although everything is fine.
So checking directly if the worker is running would be much better, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Who ever end up with this problem can try out this solution: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/messenger/deploy
I just got the news that my system can move earlier to a standard deployment process, so I hopefully won't need it no longer.